# What does the -O2 option for gcc do?

Tags: gcc, c

What does the -O2 option for gcc do?

eg. `gcc -O2 file1.c -o file1.o`

Comment: There's a detailed page at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html, or run `gcc -c -Q -O2 --help=optimizers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-O` options turn on compiler optimization. From `man gcc`:

```
   -O2 Optimize even more.  GCC performs nearly all supported
       optimizations that do not involve a space-speed tradeoff.  As
       compared to -O, this option increases both compilation time and the
       performance of the generated code.
```

For a list of the specific optimizations, refer to the manual pages.